# No more than one copy is allowed on Hp recovery manager when creating Vista discs

Tags: windows-backup

I had an issue with my laptop so I sent it to customer services for repair, and today trying to make a recovery disc it tells me that just one disc creation is allowed, which means they did this on the repair maybe.

Is there anyway to hack this to make me create a new disc recovery? or is there any software that does the same thing?

For information my laptop is an Hp DV6700.

Comment: Incredible! Sorry, but I just need to vent. Not only the one-copy recovery disk idiocy is one of the most annoying things when buying laptops (one of the reasons I never buy Dell or HP or any brand imposing such restriction), but now you have to put up with the possibility that those people that are supposed to solve your computer problems, are the ones creating a new one. Anyways... sorry about that. My answer will follow shortly below.

Comment: thanx I hope it will work

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/751858/creating-2nd-recovery-disk-set-hp-pavilion-dv6-1315tx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some advice I found:

1. See if this article helps : ["How to Reset HP Pavilion Recovery CD One Limit Restriction"](http://www.coderetard.com/2008/08/12/how-to-reset-hp-pavilion-recovery-cd-one-limit-restriction/).
2. Found this on google : "find hpcd.sys, there will be 2 copies one in windows C:\WINDOWS\SMINST and other in E: rename hpcd.bak on both and you can make another set"
3. Order the Recovery DVD from the HP website using product number in driver pages
4. Try out the [Restore Disks site](http://restoredisks.com/).

**Edit**
If the recovery cd is now unlocked but burning it hangs, then most probably your recovery partition is dead (note: one dvd is not enough, so I hope it's not simply waiting for the 2nd one!).
From this article : [HP Recovery Partition Low Disk Space](http://forums.cnet.com/5208-6122_102-0.html?threadID=273122) (for XP), I understand that HP will update the recovery partition, and may destroy it if the allocated disk space for the partition is not enough to contain all Windows Updates.
If that's the case, then your only hope AFAIK is to get a new restore cd elsewhere than from your own machine, either from the above listed sources, or download one from [Windows Vista Recovery Disc Download](http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/) (I have no first-hand knowledge regarding this source, and you need bit-torrent software for it, but it's much referenced on google).

Comment: thanx seems pretty well answering my question, all the other answers are for backup and not Vista DVD recovery

Comment: WoW great, the 2nd solution worked from the first try :), actually it's unlocked, but it always stops at 90% when burning the DVD :(

Comment: I'd recommend once you've created your discs you then use your disc creation software to created duplicates or iso images as a backup so you don't have to do it again.

Comment: thanx dude, the 2nd solution deleting hpcd.sys worked perfectly, I have the backup discs now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use free software like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) to create as many images as you like. For single machine back and recovery, Clonezilla **Live** is suitable for you.

Just burn the disk and boot from it. Follow the instructions to create the image.

Comment: But that would require one to actually have a first copy, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know of. (On Dell laptops there used to be a trick involving renaming a file that got created in system32 when you did your recovery CD. But I don't think this works anymore and it certainly can't be applied to HP because they use a different mechanism; an hidden partition). But there are a couple other possibilities.

Do note however that my answer doesn't even pretend to be definitive. The HP recovery partition is a mystery to me since I don't own, or never did, a Dell laptop. It's possible that you may get a more valid answer involving this partition, although unfortunately for you I do have my doubts because there is no reason for it to contain a complete image of the system. I sure hope I'm wrong :)

**HDD Image Backup**
Make backups of important files in your computer and uninstall all software bringing it back to a post-installation condition. You may also want to use programs like CCleaner and registry cleaners to organize things a bit.

Or, you may want to keep some essential software you know you will always depend on. The point however is to reduce your disk usage size.

Finally, Use a program like [Norton Ghost](http://www.argentuma.com/backup/software/norton-ghost.html) to create a HDD image backup to DVD. This becomes your new recovery disk(s).

**Manual System Installation**
If you already own a windows copy, just do my favorite option. Get all drivers and other software for your laptop model from HP downloads area and build a new XP installation disk with a tool like [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/).

All the best and good luck!

Comment: I have vista actually, and there is no windows copy with the pc, I am supposed to create it, but heck, customer service did it I think!

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at creating system restore disks failed when the machine decided to reboot during the middle of writing the last CD.

I called HP and explained to them what happened and they sent me recovery disks at no charge.  This was a while back so they may have changed their policy but it's worth a try.

The next best option would be to make an image of the system in its current state.  I have used [DriveImage XML](http://download.cnet.com/DriveImage-XML/3000-2242_4-10443230.html) to create an image of my operating system drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have new HP Pavlion dv6-2005ax.
hpcd.sys not working because that changed to hpdrcu.prc,
search and delete all hpdrcu.prc file. It is worked well for me.
I want to creacte another recovery disc. because ordered recovery disc is not as same as that recovery disc created from my computer. 
hp ordered recovery disc take more time to recover the OS than my recovery disc.