# Creating 2nd recovery disk set HP Pavilion dv6-1315tx

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hp-pavilion, recovery-disk

I have just recently got a HP Pavilion dv6-1315tx computer second hand. It comes with Windows 7 Home Premium pre-installed. The first thing I wanted to do was to create a recovery disk,but it seems as if the previous owner has already created a set. I am from Sri Lanka so I cannot order a Recovery Kit from HP. Their support page is confusing.

After doing a lot of research, I deleted files such as `hpdrcu.dat` from the recovery partition as well as another location. I also searched for `Rebecca.dat` but to no avail on my whole system, but still it gives the same error.

I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me a method to create a new set of disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many months of searching I finally found away. I give credit to https://sites.google.com/site/mybyways/info/hp-cyberlink .

My simplified method is first to show hidden files and folders, then find the following files:

1. C:\ProgramData\Hewlett-Packard\Recovery\hpdrcu.prc
2. C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\Recovery\hpdrcu.sys
3. D:\hpdrcu.prc

Add .bak to the ends of each of these files eg: hpdrcu.prc.bak

I do not know whether this will work on all computers, but it certainly works on mine.

Comment: in my case, there also was `%SystemRoot%\System32\Rebecca.dat`. Until it removed, HP Recovery Media Creator declined to start.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by deleting 2 files.  No need to reboot:

- D:\hpdrcu.prc
- C:\ProgramData\Hewlett-Packard\Recovery\hpdrcu.prc

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, You can create only one set of Recovery Discs as mentioned here http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=bph07143

But You can ask your previous owner for Recovery Discs and clone them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Hewlett Packard Pavilion **Slimline S5310f**, running **Windows 7 Home Premium** and was able to make **multiple** 'Factory Recovery' Disc sets. **(I only needed to locate TWO files!)**

from C drive locate the file hpdrcu.prc, and rename it hpdrcu.prc.bak 
( I located mine at:  C:\HP\ProgramData\Hewlett-Packard\Recovery\hpdrcu.prc )

then,

from the D drive locate the file: hpdrcu.prc, and rename it hpdrcu.prc.bak
( Mine was located at: D:\hpdrcu.prc )

**I only had to change these TWO files**, and after changing them and rebooting, was able to use the HP Factory Recovery to create my 3-disc Factory Recovery DVDs.

Even tho I went to Folder Options and made it show invisible files, **Search DID NOT show me these files, *I had to dig for them!***

Hope this helps anyone that has a HP s5310f Slimline PC running Windows 7 Home Premium.

Also, to make a 2nd or 3rd set, just follow the above again and again.

Answer (score -1):

For my e9250t (a 2009 machine), the culprit was three files found here:

```
D:\hpdrcu.prc
C:\ProgramData\Hewlett-Packard\Recovery\hpdrcu.prc
C:\Users\All Users\Hewlett-Packard\Recovery\hpdrcu.prc
```

All three were hidden. Just rename those files, no reboot necessary.

Comment: `c:\Users\All Users` is symlink to `C:\ProgramData`. That wasn't me who gave you **-1** though.